# Laravel call to undefined relationship [brand] on model [App\Product]

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to return my model data with resource but it says:

> Call to undefined relationship [brand] on model [App\Product].

## Code

`product.php`

```
public function brand()
{
  return $this->belongTo(Brand::class);
}
```

`brand.php`

```
public function products()
{
  return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
}
```

`controller`

```
public function show($slug)
{
  $product = Product::where('slug', $slug)->with(['photos', 'variations', 'options', 'brand'])->where('active', 'yes')->first();
  return response()->json([
    'data' => new ProductFrontResource($product),
    'message' => 'Product retrieved successfully.',
  ]);
}
```

`ProductFrontResource.php`

```
use App\Http\Resources\CategoryResource;

class ProductFrontResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        $arrayData = [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'slug' => $this->slug,
            'brand' => $this->brand->name,
            'categories' => CategoryResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('categories')),
            'created_at' => (string) $this->created_at,
            'updated_at' => (string) $this->updated_at,
        ];

        return $arrayData;
    }
}
```

**Any idea?**

## Update

If I remove `brand` from `with()` part it says:

```
Call to undefined method App\Product::belongTo()
```

Comment: belongsTo not belongTo

Comment: damn! :)))) thanks buddy.

Comment: can i make it as an answer ? :D to gain points :)

Comment: sure thing, go ahead

Comment: ah yes, noted :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change brand relationship into this.

```
public function brand()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(Brand::class);
}
```

source [laravel eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent)